# How to make stock inventory web based service..?

Tags: mysql, windows, web-services, tomcat, struts2

I want to make an application for my dad to keep track of stock trading inventory.
He trades shares for himself and for his clients and would like to keep the records.

He uses windows.
I want to provide an html page where he will enter new information and this should go to a database.

I am thinking of using struts (and windows,tomcat) and mysql to make this application. I know some stuff from college days, but would look into the tutorials to setup things and program.

Does this selection of technology looks good enough or something more easier and equally good exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve here? There's a lot of work involved in this. Certainly if you want to do it just for fun / experience then there's a very strong case for either sticking with what you're comfortable with or using tools you'd like to gain experience in. But if the only objective is to provide a tool for managing the data, why not have a look at some of the open-source/commercial packages available.

There are some [listed here](http://technical-analysis-software.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&catid=3&Itemid=26)

Comment: My objective is really to have a tool , which meets the requirements.My dad does manual bookkeeping of shares traded, buying price,sold price,profit etc for himself and his clients. I am not sure if there will be an off-the-shelf product, which I can just use, because the different tables,coloumns maintained and different reports he would like is something which needs to be customized.

Comment: Are there any off-the-shelf softwares, where you use specifify tables,columns,formulas,reports etc, and the web-based gui for data input and data output will be taken care of by the software..any such frameworks?